# ajax query my content is auto unselect how can i select thiis is the test query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I made a live chat using AJAX, which is working properly. My problem is that I have 1 second interval for the AJAX and when I want to select and copy my AJAX response or chat reply then my selected area is automatically unselected because of the AJAX. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the reason your selected text is unselected is because you are replacing the whole content of the chat. This causes the message you selected to be deleted, so obviously the selection will be released. What you should do is to just add the new messages and not replace the old messages too. You could do this by e.g. storing the latest message id that the client has received (in the front end), and send any newer messages with a higher id.

Comment: yes this is the right but my older message is selected..You ask me right answer but sir give me alternate to for select my older content (message) like as facebook meassge it is possible sir.